# Objective C can not process 2d array .count?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I've got the latest xcode which is xcode 4.6, and have this problem:

```
NSArray *array = @[@[@"a",@"b"]];
NSLog(@"%d", array[0].count);
```

Before I run it, xcode told me "Property 'count' not found on object of type 'id'".

---

But if I change it to

```
NSLog(@"%d", [array[0] count]);
```

then, everything is fine.

---

So my question is, why can't obj-c process **two_d_array[index].count** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks at the docs for `NSArray`. There is no `count` property. In fact, there are no properties at all for `NSArray`.

When you use the property syntax for a non-property method, the compiler will deal with it OK if you have an object of a specific type and there is a method of the same name. But in this case you have an `id`. So the compiler can't safely work out that your attempt to access a `count` property should be converted to a call to the `count` method.

Comment: So, the compiler treat array[0] as id but not NSArray? Should I stop use .count for every NSArray to avoid confuse?

Comment: The return value of `objectAtIndex:` is `id`. When you use the modern syntax of `array[x]` this is the same as `[array objectAtIndex:x]`. That is why `array[0]` is an `id` and not an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by typecasting as follows: `NSLog(@"%d", ((NSArray*)array[0]).count);`. XCode will let you call a method that your object won't respond to because it thinks you know what you are doing. However, if it can't find the property it will error out.